# printing a right angled triangle with asterics c#

Tags: c#

The aim is for this programme to loop from 1 through 10 and print a right angled triangle to the console window but instead it prints "+,-./01234"

```
    char star ='*';
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
        {
            star++;
            Console.WriteLine(star);
        }
        }
```

Comment: `char` doesn't work in the same way as `string`, the former being a *fundamental type* (an integer). Incrementing a `char` will only add 1 to its internal value (the ASCII code of the character it represents).

Comment: https://www.csharpstar.com/star-pattern-programs-in-csharp/

Comment: a `char` is by definition a _single_ character. Actually it is a number, that is interpreted as a character. Therefore, incrementing it does not add another character but it makes it another character. If you want more than 1 character you either need `char[]` or `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `star++;` you don't create a new string like `"**"`. You need to use a `string` for that:

```
string star = string.Empty; // use string
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
{
     star += "*"; // append a star
     Console.WriteLine(star);
}
```

Comment: string star should be an empty string

Comment: @OkekeDavid fixed it